# Row values undefined in JS controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have a table with a button on every row. On click of that button I want to pass the row values to JS controller and then assign those values to flow and invoke it.I am able to get the clicked row value in JS controller. But when I convert it to String and print specific values, I am getting `Undefined`. 
**Below is my table**

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.searchResult}" var="acc">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Name}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Date_of_Birth__c}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.BillingStreet }</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Mailing_Zip_Postal_Code__c}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Vitality_Status__c}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-form-element">

                            <lightning:button class="action-btns" value="{!acc}" variant="neutral" label="ID  V" onclick="{! c.invokeFlow }"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
```

**This is my JS controller :**

```
invokeFlow : function (cmp , event) {
var test = event.getSource().get("v.value");
test = JSON.stringify(test);
console.log('===String test==='+test); //This prints Objects
console.log('=====Value ===='+test.Name) ; //This gives undefined
```

}

**Below is the console output**
[image]

When I try to print the name directly from the console screen, this works fine. Not sure what i am missing. Any inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.stringify will converts any object in string. So Now test is a String so test.name will be undefined.

```
var test = event.getSource().get("v.value");
console.log('=====Value ===='+test.Name) ; //This gives undefined
```

Above code will work.

If you just want name then you should store name in value not whole object.

```
<lightning:button class="action-btns" value="{!acc.name}" variant="neutral" label="ID  V" onclick="{! c.invokeFlow }"/>
```

then

```
var name = event.getSource().get("v.value");
```

will be enough.

Comment: @Manjot Singh  What we need to do to get the all row values, not only the acc.name

Comment: @raju set button value="{!acc}" and then use var acc = event.getSource().get("v.value"); in js. you will get whole object